# clear the console Absolutely js

Tags: javascript, console

I had a lot of logs and errors in the console so I wrote this command:

```
console.clear();
```

then in the console I got this message: "Console was cleared", can I remove the message also?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. Why don't you just click on the button to clear the console?

Comment: I want that it will be by the code

Comment: Doubt you can do it